# How to return a background task to be in the foreground?

Tags: shell, background-process, jobs

I would like to know how to stop a running *process* after appending it with `&`.

For example, I would like to install software `foo`. Now, assume, `foo` has many dependancies, it takes an hour to finish. So, I do: `yum install foo &`. But I would like to stop that on-going process either by making it foreground (the actual premise of my question) so I can interrupt it, or through other methods if necessary.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not seem to stop this.

Comment: Try looking for the PID: `pu aux | grep foo`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the terminal you launched the command from is still open, you can get it back by running `fg`.

If it is not, identify the process ID by running `ps aux | grep yum`  or just `pgrep yum` and then use `kill PID`. Or, if you know you only have one `yum` instance, run `pkill yum`.

Comment: So, this will kill the entire `yum` process. Not specific to that `foo` thread?

Comment: @CONtext not sure what you mean. The "foo thread" is the yum process. In any case, the `fg` doesn't kill anything, it just brings a backgrounded job back to the foreground.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in the same shell, you can always foreground that process with `fg` (if your shell supports it) at that point you can perform your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>C</kbd>.

As others have mentioned, you can use a wide variety of `ps` and `kill` options.

If you want, you can even use `top` and filter to your username and kill that way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
kill -QUIT `pidof yum`
```

This will stop, terminate this process.
It may be required to use some better force than `QUIT` signal, then try `TERM` and after that try `KILL`.

You may be also a little more lazy and just do this:

```
killall -QUIT yum
```

This will hit all processes named `yum`.

Answer (score 0):

The key combination you are looking for isn't

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>

you use that when you interrupt the process (equivalent to using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>)

If you <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> instead you would place the job in the background, similar to using <kbd>&</kbd> at the end.

However this way you would be able to bring the process back to the foreground by using <kbd>fg</kbd>

Alternatively you can look for the pid using `pidof` as mentioned by Scyld